# Apache configuration with Node.js and phpmyadmin

Tags: node.js, apache, proxypass

I'm trying to run an apache server that has phpmyadmin setup with a node.js web application as well.  I'm having issue properly configuring the apache to do this successfully.

Example:

```
http://localhost:3000 is the url for node.js web application
http://localhost:80 is the url for the normal site
http://localhost/phpmyadmin is the url to access the phpmyadmin client
```

Is there a way to configure the ProxyPass/ProxyReversePass to make this work?  I've been missing with different configurations and can't get it to work properly.

http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache

I tried this link, but currently when the function trigger restful calls, the url is not process correctly.

Example

```
http://localhost:3000/report (GET)
```

won't work with

```
http://localhost/report (GET)
```

Any advice appreciated,
thanks
D

Comment: Why would you want to serve a nodejs site through Apache? Nodejs is pretty good at HTTP, isn't it? (I don't know the answer and I'm reading that link now.)

Comment: I think the only reason is because I have mysql set up and i want to use phpmyadmin as well..and its configured to apache already.....

Comment: Ah, and you want the entire outside HTTP server on port 80. Yeah, that's a pretty good reason. Seems to be exactly what the article is about though. What doesn't work? What does "won't work with" mean?

Comment: The article is about different vhosts with different `ServerName`s, is that your issue? You want different URLs on the same domain to come into nodejs and apache? `example.com/phpmyadmin` to Apache and `example.com/report` to Nodejs?

Comment: the problem is that its not recognizing example.com/report  which should be reverse proxy to example:3000/report.  But that's not happening. I basically want all call to / to go to :3000.  This won't solve the whole how do you handle phpmyadmin.  But wanted to take baby steps

Comment: Only the index `/` works? That's weird... `<Location />` should get em all, but I'm no expert. For /phpmyadmin (later) you might want to look at the `Alias` directive and you'll probably have to reset the index script to `index.php` for `<Location /phpmyadmin/>`. I dunno, sorry

Comment: @darewreck, did you solve this problem? If so plz share with us the solution.